# Strange error when deleting directory from Java: 0 bytes, access denied

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have written method that recursively deletes directory with its contents.
Code is executed on Windows - Eclipse - JVM7

Here's the code:

```
    /**
 * Empty and delete a folder with recursion.
 * 
 * @param folder
 *            folder to empty
 */
public static boolean rmdir(final String folderPath, boolean deleteParent) {
    File folder = new File(folderPath);

    // check if folder file is a real folder
    if (folder.isDirectory()) {
        File[] list = folder.listFiles();

        if (list != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                File tmpF = list[i];
                if (tmpF.isDirectory())
                    rmdir(tmpF.toString(), true);

                tmpF.delete();
            }
        }

        if (deleteParent && !folder.delete()) {
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When the code is executed no error is thrown, saying that directory has been deleted successfully.
When I open drive to confirm deletion, I can still see the folder which is now 0 bytes in size with "Access denied" error when trying to open it.

[image: Directory properties]

[image: Directory security]

EDIT:

I am administrator, have all permissions and can R/W to this folder from Windows explorer (before Java breaks it).
My question is has anyone seen this before and what could be the cause of this??

One more thing:
It seems that the directory gets set to "DeleteOnExit" instead of "Delete" right away.
Because when program ends in Lotus Notes or Eclipse directory disappears.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-the-file-permission-in-java/

Comment: This happened to me once on my virus infected windows. No more windows :)

Comment: d:\Programm Files is restricted area. try to start your programm/ JVM as administrator

Comment: Check the return value of `tmpF.delete();` if it returns false, then the delete wasn't successful.
And you need to have write permission on the folder and its parent to do a delete operation.

Comment: tmpF.delete(); returns true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got this resolved...

I was not Java issue, it was Lotus Notes/Domino issue.

Here comes the long sentence:

It seems when Lotus Notes/Domino thread creates folder "A" and some files in it using LotusScript `mkdir`, `rmdir`, and other IO methods and then executes Java VM which tries to delete folder "A" with all files in it, parent thread (Lotus Notes/Domino) gets corrupted and loses directory structure handle which results in error above.

Solution to the problem is simple `Dir$()` statement after Java finishes folder deletion.
When `Dir$()` is executed, phantom folder disappears.
Probably because the `Dir$()` call refreshes and releases whatever should be refreshed and released internally.

Comment: What does this mean? `Dir$()`

Comment: @aaiezza It is LotusScript Sub (function) to list all items in current directory.

Answer (score -1):

Java is probably not the best language to solve this problem in. You can do this with batch file programming in one line: `rmdir <directory-to-completely-remove> /s /q`. If you absolutely must do this in Java, then you can run this command from a Java program on windows with: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start /min cmd.exe /K \"rmdir <directory-to-remove> /s /q & exit\"");`

Comment: This code creates the same error when executed from Java.
However it works like a charm when the root cause for error has been resolved.